# Specific layout advise

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm about to start building my xml layout for a fragment but I'm not sure what is the best way to do it in term of performances and fiting as many screen size as possible.
First of all, here is the layout:

[image]

So my issues are on deciding what kind of layout to adopt? The easiest would be nested LinearLayout but I remember reading somewhere that it wasnt good for performances...
If RelativeLayout, does it really work to be able to fit as many screens as possible? Or how to do it?
Also, is using include element good for performances?

I'm seeking any advises on how to achieve this the best way.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use linear layout vertical with relative layout in it and in the relative layout use the liner layout horizontal and in the linear layout horizontal use the linear layout vertical.

use this format for ur code
liner layout vertical -> relative layout -> liner layout horizontal -> relative layout-> liner layout vertical -> textview

for example u can try it like tis also ...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

u can use more text view like this in ur project ...
try this it may help u ....

thanxx.

edit answer...

here for making a border in between use

```
<View 
   android:layout_height="1dp"  
   android:background= "#fff"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
  />
```

Comment: Thx! I will try that! How to make the borders btw?

Comment: here i have addded the code for the border check it out ...please mark the answer if u find it right or upvote it  @Makoto